# hibernatetemplate.findByCriteria method override to return Map<OneColumnValue,BeanClassObject>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Give me example .

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate`, I want to override the method `findByCriteria(criteria)` to return  a map.

Map in the combination of <k,v>

> k->one column value (primary key)
>
> v->relevant class Object.(to collect remaining values)